# Measurable function, checking a proof.

Tags: measure-theory

I'm studying and trying to proof this proposition. This is my attempt to prove it, and I can't see how i can improve it, although I'm not very convinced by the proof. Any help would be appreciated.

The proposition is the following:

A function $f:(\Omega,\mathcal{A})\to(\overline{\mathbb{R}},\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}}))$, is measurable if and only if for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$, $$\{x\in\Omega:f(x)>c\}\in\mathcal{A}.$$

My attempt:

Suppose that $f$ is a measurable function, and let $c\in\mathbb{R}$, since $f$ is measurable we have that for every $B\subset\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$, $f^{-1}(B)\subset\mathcal{A}$, so, for the set $B=(c,\infty]\subset\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$, we have that $f^{-1}(c,\infty]=\{f>c\}\in\mathcal{A}$ therefore; 
$$\{x\in\Omega:f(x)>c\}\in\mathcal{A}.$$

Inversely, suppose that $\{x\in\Omega:f(x)>c\}\in\mathcal{A}$, for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$, and $f$ a function. Let $B\subset\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$, then $B=(c,\infty]$
$$f^{-1}(c,\infty]=\{x\in\Omega:f(x)>c\}\in\mathcal{A}$$
Therefore $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: "Let $B\subset \mathcal{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$, then $B=(c,\infty]$" is not true - clearly $(1,2]$ is in the Borel algebra. but isn't of this form. However, if you can show that $\mathcal{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$ can be generated by sets of the form $(c,\infty]$ (which may well be how you defined the same), the proof above goes through with minimal changes.

Comment: Oh! i see, thanks, i was searching and now i have the right way to prove that $\{(c,\infty]\}$ generate the $\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$, thanks for that!